# KendoUI grid replacement, need a grid that has better performance

Tags: javascript, grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been using kendoui components for a while. But it looks like my new project needs something else. It's very disappointing. 
Does anyone know of a grid component that has better performance when it comes to reading lots of data?
I get about 200 or more row updates 3 times a second. and need to have 3 maybe 4 tables open. Data needs to arrive quickly to be visible by the user.
The issue i am having with kendoui is that if there are two many rows the whole user interface freezes. and even when i lower the amount of data and the browser no longer freezes, any action the user is trying to take gets interrupted. So say he tries to select a row and then do something with it, the data gets refreshed before he can do anything.
I need a grid that will refresh the data without completely loosing track of everything else while it is done. I don't need a huge amount of functionality, so no data editing. Only display, sort, show and hide columns select row for some action.

Comment: if you are re-painting a whole grid 3 times a second, anything would be slow since the sheer volume of static html alone will burden the browser. you should only touch the rows if not cells that change... Look into mvc or mvvc for a way out of the madness.

Comment: That can't be done with kendoui. each time the cell is edited the grid actually refreshes. That is the issue i am having. I need a grid that will change the grid cell. Ideally i would like to have a grid that can have an observable object bound to it. and when an item in the array changes the grid reflects that with a change to the cell. Again, not the way kendoui grid works. This is why i am looking for advice on a grid that does do that.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use set methods of the dataItem when you want to avoid notifying the widgets that are listening for changes.

So for example if you are updating a model like this

```
dataItem.set('FirstName',newValue);
 //change it like this
dataItem.FirstName = newValue
```

finally call grid.refresh() to display all changes at once.

Comment: I don't use the set() method. If i did i would have some 1000 refreshes every second. Calling the grid.refresh() method 3 times a second still loads it 3 times a second. I need to somehow edit each cell separately, not loading the whole grid.